Adjusting position of raster layer in QGIS
I have a number of raster layers in QGIS, open-source or provided by other people. One of them is slightly off in position, about 100m in a map that is 10km square.
Is there a way to add an arbitrary offset, in km or degrees, to this layer in QGIS?

If you can match up locations on the raster with landmarks, and it sounds like you can, otherwise how would you know it's 100m off, you can use the georeferencer to shift to a more accurate location https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html
